# How to use a shift calculation with a cumulative value in a data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, shift

I have a data.table with the following layout

```
TestData <- data.table(Threshold = 20,
                       Upto = 100,
                       Demand = c(0,0,5,0,50,10,10,10,10,50,20,60),
                       Stock  = c(100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
```

The stock value should be calculated as a cumulative value with the formula:

> If Stock (previous row) minus Demand (current row) is less or equal
>   than the threshold, than update the current cell in Stock with the
>   value in "Upto". Else update the value of stock (current row) with stock (previous row) minus demand (current row).

Then the procedure should begin again. The result should look like the following:

```
TestData <- data.table(Threshold = 20,
                       Upto = 100,
                       Demand = c(0,0,5,0,50,10,10,10,10,50,20,60),
                       Stock = c(100,100,95,95,45,35,25,100,90,40,100,40))

    Threshold Upto Demand Stock
 1:        20  100      0   100
 2:        20  100      0   100
 3:        20  100      5    95
 4:        20  100      0    95
 5:        20  100     50    45
 6:        20  100     10    35
 7:        20  100     10    25
 8:        20  100     10   100
 9:        20  100     10    90
10:        20  100     50    40
11:        20  100     20   100
12:        20  100     60    40
```

What I have done is the following:

```
TestData[, Stock:= ifelse(cumsum(shift(Stock, 0, type="lead") - Demand) <= Threshold,
                     Upto,
                     cumsum(shift(Stock, 0, type="lead") - Demand))]
```

But after the first update the calculation stops and showing 100 each time tile the end. The first value in stock is a initial value I manually set. Thank you!

Comment: I think you might need a loop for this since each iteration depends on the value of the previous iteration (previous day's stock)

Comment: @docendodiscimus Yeah, I think a loop is needed because there's a reset rule (with cumulative demand restarting after a gap of one row after it hits 80).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can live with a looped solution. I don't think this is doable with dplyr (or data.table), but I would love for someone to prove me wrong.

```
for (i in 2:nrow(TestData)) {
  # If stock - demand <= threshold, restock
  if ((TestData[i-1, "Stock"] - TestData[i, "Demand"]) <= TestData[i, "Threshold"]) 
  {
    TestData[i, "Stock"] <- TestData[i-1, "Upto"]
  }
  # Else update stock with stock - demand
  else 
  {
    TestData[i, "Stock"] <- TestData[i-1, "Stock"] - TestData[i, "Demand"]
  }
}
```

Comment: You could store `TestData[i-1, "Stock"] - TestData[i, "Demand"]` as a temp variable in each iteration in the loop, since otherwise you may compute it twice in some iterations. `remaining = TestData[i-1, "Stock"] - TestData[i, "Demand"]; TestData[i, "Stock"] <- if (remaining <= TestData[i, "Threshold"]) TestData[i-1, "Upto"] else remaining`

Comment: Thank you all. I have choosen this as an answer as it suits best to my real problem I have.

Answer (score 4):

here is a `data.table` solution. The innovation is at the `by` grouping. Please do post any boundary cases that this solution is failing at.

```
TestData <- data.table(Threshold = 20,
                       Upto = 100,
                       Demand = c(0,0,5,0,50,10,10,10,10,50,20,60),
                       Stock  = c(100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))

#to see by grouping
#TestData[,trunc(cumsum(Demand)/(Threshold - Upto))]

TestData[, Stock2 := c(Upto[1], Upto[1] - cumsum(Demand[-1])),
    by=trunc(cumsum(Demand)/(Threshold - Upto))]
TestData
```

Answer (score 2):

Was a tricky one. Did it with a do-while principle:

```
upVal     = 100
threshVal = 20
cumVals   <- TestData$Demand
cumMaster <- cumsum(cumVals) 


repeat{
    IND <- cumMaster>=upVal-threshVal
    cumVals[min(which(IND == TRUE))] <- 0
    cumMaster[IND] <- cumsum(cumVals[IND])
    if(all(cumMaster<upVal-threshVal)){
        break
    }
}

TestData$Stock <- 100 - cumMaster
```

The result

```
TestData$Stock
```